# Saving and loading class data stored in a binary file in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, serialization

I am trying to save and load data into a binary file so I can retrieve the contents later. The code I has used to work if each data item was the same size, but with this class data, it doesn't work. I made some adjustments to try to fix this by saving a data size variable as well. This however didn't work either.
Here's my class:

```
class Player
{
public:
    Player();
    Player(int playerID, std::string name, std::string country, int startYear, std::vector<int> rankPerYear);
    ~Player();

    int getRank() { return rank; }

private:
    int playerID;
    std::string name;
    std::string country;
    int rankingPts;
    int rank;
    int startYear;
    std::vector<int> rankPerYear;
    Schedule schedule;
    PlayerStats playerStats;
};
```

And here are my load and save functions:

```
void GameData::saveGame(std::string fileName)
{
    std::ofstream file;
    fileName += ".bin";
    file.open(fileName.c_str(), std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);

    size_t tempSize = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++) {
        tempSize = sizeof(players[i]);
        file.write((char*)&tempSize, sizeof(size_t));

        file.write((char*)&players[i], tempSize);
    }

}

void GameData::loadGame(std::string fileName)
{
    players.clear();
    fileName += ".bin";
    if (std::ifstream(fileName)) {
        std::ifstream file;
        file.open(fileName.c_str(), std::ios::binary | std::ios::in);
        if (!file.is_open()) {
            std::cout << "Error while opening the file";
        }
        else {
            std::string temp;
            int location = 0;
            size_t tempSize = 0;
            Player player;
            while (std::getline(file, temp)) {
                file.seekg(location, std::ios::beg);
                file.read((char*)&tempSize, sizeof(size_t));
                file.seekg(sizeof(size_t) + location, std::ios::beg);
                file.read((char*)&player, tempSize);
                players.push_back(player);
                location += sizeof(size_t) + tempSize;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        saveGame(fileName);
    }
}
```

I am saving the players to a vector of Players. When I try to run this I get the error:

```
Exception thrown at 0x0F485097 (vcruntime140d.dll) in Ping Pong Manager.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x081BCE20.
```

When debugging this I found that it would save some of the data correctly, but would then crash before it finished. So I know it's partially working.
I have tried many different things but cannot figure my problem. Thanks for the help.

Comment: For some reason, these erroneous "binary file reading / writing" examples seem to be an epidemic here on SO.  This is at least the third one just today with the same errors, and one of many (probably thousands) of examples in total.  Unless you're writing `C` code or dealing with `C` compatible types, none of this will work correctly in `C++`.

Comment: [This test program](http://ideone.com/Hkcbe4) determines if `Player` is a POD type.  Since it is not a POD type, you cannot use it for binary reading or writing as you're doing now.

Comment: For example, I wrote this earlier http://stackoverflow.com/a/42729331/4581301 . It primarily deals with a `std::string`, but touches on `std::vector` as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot serialize STL containers directly since they contains pointers.

The common way is to write the field one-by-one, using specialized methods for things that contains pointers to heap.

Please consider a serialization library, which generates the code for you. Here's a list:

[Boost.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/serialization/doc/)

[Cap'n'Proto](https://capnproto.org/)

[FlatBuffers](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/)

Comment: Which library would be best for me to use with my current structure of classes and subclasses? Boost seems really complicated and hard to implement with many different classes.